# Why url is required for timestamping when signing the code

Tags: code-signing, signtool

Why url is required for timestamping when signing the code ? Why it doesn't use system time ?

Answer (score 1):

Your system time might be incorrect (either accidentally or deliberately). Using an external timestamp service removes your local system clock from the operation.

Comment: Same thing can happen to server too.

Comment: Yes, that is true. Trusted timestamp services have mitigation plans for that failure mode, of course.

Comment: Is it possible that I can timestamp without any server ? without having internet connection ? Or use system time. I can run make own timestamp server and run as local, but thats just overkill.